# Created package 'not available'

Tags: r, package

I used RStudio to create an R package ('cryptArith').  The build went fine and all relevant R files are present and functional (checked independently).  When I try to load the package and use the functions I get this:

> install.packages('cryptArith')
> Warning message:
> package ‘cryptArith’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)

I have been unable to find any information about the source of this error.

Comment: There's no package on CRAN by the name `cryptArith`. Where do you think it was uploaded to such that R will find it, download it, and install it? If you created it locally, then perhaps `install.packages("/path/to/cryptArith....")`.

Comment: For completeness, it looks like you have a [repo](https://github.com/rcgayle/cryptArith) for this but haven't pushed anything to it, further suggesting (yes, just inference) that you haven't pushed your package to CRAN or a public repository of R packages. I hope the `"/path/to/.."` suggestion worked for you, otherwise please provide more information on where it is made available. For instance, if you have made a private repo somewhere on some web site, R is particular about what goes where.

Comment: I created the package cryptArith using RStudio.  I shoudn't have to push it up to CRAN or anywhere else to use it locally on my machine.

Comment: That's correct. But because of that, `install.packages("cryptArith")` won't work, since its default mode is to look for a package of that name on the repos you have configured. It *is* possible to use a local filesystem that is a valid R repo dir-structure, something like `options(repos=c("file:///path/to/myrepo", "https://cran.rstudio.com"))` means that `c:/path/to/myrepo` has at least `PACKAGES` and `src/contrib/PACKAGES` plus your package tarballs. If you don't want to go that route, then take my first suggestion of `install.packages("path/to/cryptArith-1.0.0.tar.gz")` (whatever version).